# TOR with Python (stem) hanging on initialization

Tags: python, windows, tor

I'm having some trouble using tor with python and I don't quite know where to go from here.

System/packages:
Windows 10

Python 3.8 (via jupyter lab)

stem

tor (tor.exe added to PATH)

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import stem

proxy_port = 9050
def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print(line)

tor = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(proxy_port) },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines, take_ownership=True
)
```

It outputs one line and then just sits

```
Oct 23 15:00:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
```

**edit**
When I edit out the boostrap print line, I also get these warnings:

```
[warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will resolve to D:\projects\Valuator\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Oct 29 08:44:26.812 [warn] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is relative and will resolve to D:\projects\Valuator\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
```

Before running I made sure there were no tor.exe processes going, and I can confirm that it does start a tor.exe process in the task manager

I've also tried killing my firewall and that doesn't make any difference.

Any suggestions of how to proceed/next steps? I'm at a loss for what to try next.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works just fine on MacOS. You would get an error, if tor was not in the PATH. It should go without saying but just to be safe, have you already opened Tor after installation the normal way? There is a lot of configs done on the fly before first run. Is it an option to uninstall and make a fresh install?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - I deleted/reinstalled TOR to a different location, and I physically opened the browser without issue.

Comment: but problem still persists?

Comment: If you remove `if "Bootstrapped " in line:` are any other useful log messages printed? Try removing `take_ownership` or adding `tor.wait()` after launching since take_ownership "asserts ownership over the tor process so it aborts if this python process terminates or a Controller we establish to it disconnects". The process may terminate immediately after running your code since Python will quit since there is no more code.

Comment: Killing firewall process may not help. You should explicitely allow tor.exe everything in firewall rules.

Comment: @drew010 I removed the bootstrapped line and got some other warnings that appeared. I've updated above. I think what may be happening is I have some outdated tor files from an old install. I noticed in [username]/appdata/roaming/tor it references files that were installed previously. I'm going to delete that directory and reinstall Tor - hopefully that fixes

Comment: The additional log entries indicate a warning with the GeoIP file which shouldn't affect bootstrapping (I don't think anyway). I copied your example, keeping the "take_ownership" option and ran it on Windows 10 without issue. Tor bootstrapped, connected, and then terminated once that finished. When it is stuck bootstrapping, do you still see the tor.exe process running? You might have a firewall issue with that Tor process that is keeping it from accessing the network.

Comment: Also, make sure to use the expert bundle on Windows (Also, make sure to use the expert bundle on windows: https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/10.0.2/tor-win32-0.4.4.5.zip) not the binaries from the browser bundle. When I tested I was able to get it working by using the Tor Browser bundle executables, though the expert bundle should be easier to get going.

Comment: @drew010 thanks - the issue was the outdated files in the appdata directory. I deleted that directory, deleted the tor browser install, reinstalled from windows exe installer, manually ran it once, and then it launches correctly in python thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was an outdated old install in [username]/appdata/roaming/tor. I had moved the directory I installed Tor to, but didn't know to clear that folder first. Once I deleted that and reinstalled Tor browser, everything ran correctly.